# Javascript replace don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to make a script that gets the first character of a word, but some words a excluded. so to filter those words a use a Regular expression and replace them with nothing.
here my code:

```
$(document).on("keyup","input[name=name]",function(){
    var val = $(this).val().replace("/((golfpark|golfcourse|course|golfclub|golfbaan|golf|en|&|country|club|gc)|[\s]([^\s]{0,3})[\s]|[\s])/i","").substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    $("select[name=char_link]").val(val);
});
```

for example if i type 'Golfbaan & country club demo' in the input field the outpus must be 'D' from 'demo'.
here is de jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qCUrH/

Comment: remove semicolon(`;`) in this `var val = $(this).val()[;].replace(...` :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have an unnecessary semicolon after `val()`. Your code is throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . ".

Change:

```
$(this).val();.replace(...);
```

To:

```
$(this).val().replace(...);
```

---

Furthermore, in order for the regular expression to work you need to remove the quotations.

Change:

```
.replace("/MyPattern/i", ...);
```

To:

```
.replace(/MyPattern/i, ...);
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qCUrH/4/).

Comment: that makes no differance

Comment: That's because you're trying to replace an entire string, not a regex pattern. Remove the quotations around the regex. http://jsfiddle.net/qCUrH/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var val = $(this).val().replace(/((golfpark|golfcourse|course|golfclub|golfbaan|golf|en|&|country|club|gc)|[\s]([^\s]{0,3})[\s]|[\s])/ig,"").substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
```

no `;` after `$(this).val();`

Also you have to remove the enclosing `"` around the regex in the `replace()`
Also you are missing the global flag in the regex `/reged/ig`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Xuv5/)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string as the first argument to replace. If you remove the " quotes around your regular expression, it will be treated as a regular expression.

```
$(document).on("keyup","input[name=name]",function(){
    var val = $(this).val().replace(/((golfpark|golfcourse|course|golfclub|golfbaan|golf|en|&|country|club|gc)|[\s]([^\s]{0,3})[\s]|[\s])/i,"").substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    $("select[name=char_link]").val(val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it wordt but only once, it should be multiple times

Comment: add a flag 'g' to your regex

`/((golfpark|golfcourse|course|golfclub|golfbaan|golf|en|&|country|club|gc)|[\s]([^\s]{0,3})[\s]|[\s])/gi`